# Is it possible to use say-command line in linux terminal? (not espeak)

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, text-to-speech, manjaro, espeak

i'm trying to search for the best tts. and finally I found that say command in mac-os terminal is the most natural speaker engine.
but I want to use it in my linux OS.(Ubuntu or manjaro)
Is it any way to use it in linux?

I EMPHASIS that I don't want to use espeaker. Just say command.
thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`say` is a command line interface to  [Mac OS X Speech Synthesis Manager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/speech_synthesis_manager), which does not exist outside Apple products. So... no.

> I EMPHASIS that I don't want to use espeaker. Just say command. thanks for your help

If you just want `say` command, you can alias an open-source engine to it; but it will not sound the same. It's not about the `say` command, but the TTS engine it invokes.

However, I doubt you tested all possibilities. IBM has a rather good TTS engine, which is available via a web service; so does Google. Both are free to use (up to a monthly limit). Of course, you have to be online to use those.

Answer (score 8):

There is a command line tool called `spd-say`. This is found on Ubuntu as well and here are some links for some additional reference.

[Ubuntu Manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/spd-say.1.html)

[GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-aplay-and-spd-say-command-in-linux/)

`spd-say "some text"` will say the text with the speech dispatcher.

Taken from Ubuntu Manpages:

> spd-say  sends text-to-speech output request to speech-dispatcher process which handles it
> and ideally outputs the result to the audio system.

Comment: The apt package for this tool is [speech-dispatcher](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/speech-dispatcher.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `espeak-ng` https://github.com/espeak-ng/espeak-ng.

installed and tested on my arch linux.